# Doctrine PHP is already defined

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm having an issue with doctrine inner joins.

```
$request = $em->getRepository('FYPFYPDesignBundle:SessionDesign');
$qb = $request->createQueryBuilder('SessionDesign');
$query = $qb
    ->select('SessionDesign.sessionID',        'SessionDesign.created','fos_user.username', 'fos_user.email', 'fos_user.fcid')
        ->from('FYPUserBundle:User', 'fos_user')
        ->innerJoin('fos_user.fcid', 'fos_user', 'ON', 'SessionDesign.sessionID = fos_user.fcid')       
        ->where('fos_user.emailok = true')
        ->getQuery();
    $result = $query->getResult();
```

The error it gives me is:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                                                                   
  [Semantical Error] line 0, col 218 near 'fos_user ON SessionDesign.sessionID': Error: 'fos_user' is already defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an alias twice in your querybuilder.

Change:

```
 ->from('FYPUserBundle:User', 'fos_user')
            ->innerJoin('fos_user.fcid', 'fos_user', 'ON', 'SessionDesign.sessionID = fos_user.fcid')
```

To:

```
 ->from('FYPUserBundle:User', 'fos_user')
            ->innerJoin('fos_user.fcid', 'fcid', 'ON', 'SessionDesign.sessionID = fos_user.fcid')
```

Assuming fcid is an entity you want to join to.

Note I'm not sure *why* you're doing what you're doing, but that's what's causing the error.

Edit for more info.

If joining sessiondesign with no doctrine entity relationship (looks like that's what you're doing):

```
->join('YourBundle:SessionDesign', 's', 'WITH', 's.sessionID = fos_user.fcid')
```

Comment: What do you mean not why I'm doing what I'm doing? Is there a better way to handle joins?

Comment: Does sessiondesign have a relation to fos_user?

Comment: Hmmm I guess not. I'm really new to doctrine so I'm kind of lost with this. 

I added this

class SessionDesign extends BaseSessionDesign {
     /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fcid", referencedColumnName="User")
    *
    */
     protected $sessionID;
}

Comment: Mark my question as useful (original issue is solved) so we don't have to try solve this in the comments, make another question and paste your entities and their relationships and the query you have so far and I'll be happy to help :)